# Why does the game tell me I am using too much iron?

Tags: civilization-5

I am constantly getting the notification that I am using more iron than I have. However, I have some iron and it does not show up as in use:

[image: resources panel showing iron: 7 total, 0 used]

How can I find out where my iron is in use? Should that use not show up in this information panel? And how can I see how much iron I need to obtain?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me.  Doesn't seem like you're using any Iron at all.  You haven't been getting/gifting a lot of iron-based units, have you?

Comment: @agent86 No, I have not. Thanks for the suggestion, will try restarting the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in the game. I can't reproduce the circumstances under which it happened.

I saved the game, restarted the game application and loaded the saved game again. Afterwards the message was gone.